# Remove the element completely after animation, each time. - only using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, ember-cli

How ever simple the query may seem, its boggling me since a couple of hours and here it is -

https://jsfiddle.net/230cLpnd/1/

In the jsFiddle above, i am trying to remove the element [ `display:none;` ] after the animation is complete. and reverse the same when it needs to be shown. But due to the use of `display: none;`, the transition is not applied too.

how can i completely remove the element each time the animation is complete.

https://jsfiddle.net/230cLpnd, here, Without the use of display none, the transition takes place, but the element is not completely hidden, even on `width: 0%;`

EDIT: adjusting height is not to be considered. It is being set by an external source.

EDIT 2: As in the second fiddle, the Animation is to slide right to hide the content and slide left while showing the content.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting `display` to be `none`, which, as you've discovered, isn't transitionable, you could set the `height` to be 0. By playing around with the various `transition` attributes, you can prevent the `height` from actually transitioning, achieving the effect you're after.

I've also added a transition on the `opacity` for you to make things look a bit smoother, but that's a matter of personal taste.

And, to save you the extra markup you had to clear your floated elements, I've included a "clearfix" pseudo-element on the container.

---

**OPTION 1: Without transitioning height**

```js
var  handles=document.querySelectorAll(".handle"),
     x=handles.length;
while(x--)
    handles[x].addEventListener("click",function(){
      this.parentNode.querySelector(".content").classList.toggle("hide");
    });
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:sans-serif;margin:0;padding:0;}
.container{
  background:#ff0;
  border:1px solid #f00;
  margin:20px auto;
  width:90%;
}
.container::after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  height:0;
  width:0;
}
.content{
  background:#0f0;
  display: block;
  float:right;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:20px 10px;
  transition-duration:0s,.5s,.5s,.5s;
  transition-property:max-height,padding,opacity,width;
  transition-timing-function:ease-in-out;
  white-space:nowrap;
  width:85%;
}
.content.hide{
  max-height:0;
  padding:0px;
  opacity:0;
  transition-delay:.5s,0s,0s,0s;
  width:0px;
 }
.handle{
  background:#aaa;
  float:right;
  height:100%;
  width:10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content hide">Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br></div>
  <div class="handle">click<br>to<br>toggle</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content hide">Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br></div>
  <div class="handle">click<br>to<br>toggle</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content hide">Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br></div>
  <div class="handle">click<br>to<br>toggle</div>
</div>
```

---

**OPTION 2: Transitioning `height` with value set inline**

```js
var  handles=document.querySelectorAll(".handle"),
     x=handles.length;
while(x--)
    handles[x].addEventListener("click",function(){
      this.parentNode.querySelector(".content").classList.toggle("hide");
    });
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box;font-family:sans-serif;margin:0;padding:0;}
.container{
  background:#ff0;
  border:1px solid #f00;
  margin:20px auto;
  width:90%;
}
.container::after{
  content:"";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
  height:0;
  width:0;
}
.content{
  background:#0f0;
  display: block;
  float:right;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:20px 10px;
  transition-duration:.5s;
  transition-property:height,padding,opacity,width;
  transition-timing-function:ease-in-out;
  white-space:nowrap;
  width:85%;
}
.content.hide{
  height:0px!important;
  padding:0px;
  opacity:0;
  width:0px;
 }
.handle{
  background:#aaa;
  float:right;
  height:100%;
  width:10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content hide" style="height:125px;">Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br></div>
  <div class="handle">click<br>to<br>toggle</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content hide" style="height:150px;">Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br></div>
  <div class="handle">click<br>to<br>toggle</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content hide" style="height:175px;">Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br>Content longer that the main<br></div>
  <div class="handle">click<br>to<br>toggle</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the snippet. I will have multiple such container, hence i am using class. Does this work only with Id ?. I have tried it with the "classes" here https://jsfiddle.net/230cLpnd/2/, but it does not seem to do the transition. Is there a way to use classes instead?

Comment: Can you please point in https://jsfiddle.net/230cLpnd/2/, whats been done wrong ?

Comment: I've updated the Snippet to use classes instead of IDs, to allow you to use this multiple times on the same page, which also requires some edits to the JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you very much for the changes, but i had this requirement of not being able to use height for manipulation. It is being set by an external source. is it possible with our using the height?

Comment: Also, after using your snippet in my environment, which has, ember-cli, data-equalizer, the element still does not seem to transition and hide. only the opacity is transitioning though. I am just wondering if there was a way you could have a look.  :|

Comment: I've updated the Snippet to use `max-height` instead of `height`. Depending on how the `height` is being set, you may need to append `!important` to the value of `max-height`.

Comment: wow, yes ..`max-height` was an improvement, although i was already trying `!important` .. the width animation still does not seem to apply. Looking into it now.

Comment: Actually, if the height is being set by an external source, I'd wager that it's not being set on the `.content.hide` class so you could still use `height` instead of `max-height` **and** have it transitioning. I had assumed from your comments elsewhere that you didn't *want* the `height` to transition not that you though it couldn't be done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110165/discussion-between-archer-and-shaggy).